# How to mount SMB share from terminal using keychain?

Tags: macos, terminal, mount, smb

I need to be able mount SAMBA (SMB sharing) from terminal, for MAC OS versions (10.7). Is there a way to use mount_smbfs with keychain so I don't get prompt the username/password or have to add it to the command? I'm quite new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No problem; unfortunately I don't have any experience with SMB on Mac myself, so I'm afraid I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `man nsmb.conf`. This is a configuration file that should be located at ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf (or potentially at /etc/nsmb.conf) and allows you to store configuration details in there, like passwords. It's not the keychain, and thus not encrypted, but it saves from having to put the password in the command.